# In Python, how can I update multiple rows in a DataFrame with a Series?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below.

```
              a    b    c    d
2010-07-23  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-07-26  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-07-27  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-07-28  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-07-29  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-07-30  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-08-02  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-08-03  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-08-04  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-08-05  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

And I have a series as below.

```
    2010-07-23
a           1
b           2
c           3
d           4
```

I want to update the DataFrame with the series as below. How can I do?

```
              a    b    c    d
2010-07-23  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-07-26  1    2    3    4
2010-07-27  1    2    3    4
2010-07-28  1    2    3    4
2010-07-29  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-07-30  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-08-02  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-08-03  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-08-04  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-08-05  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Thank you very much for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is one column instead `Series` in `s` add [`DataFrame.squeeze`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html) with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) by length of date range, last pass to [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
r = pd.date_range('2010-07-26','2010-07-28')
df.update(pd.concat([s.squeeze()] * len(r), axis=1, keys=r).T)
print (df)
              a    b    c    d
2010-07-23  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-07-26  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
2010-07-27  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
2010-07-28  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
2010-07-29  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-07-30  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-08-02  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-08-03  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-08-04  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-08-05  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Or you can use [`np.broadcast_to`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) for repeat `Series`:

```
r = pd.date_range('2010-07-26','2010-07-28')

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.broadcast_to(s.squeeze().values, (len(r),len(s))), 
                  index=r, 
                  columns=s.index)
print (df1)
            a  b  c  d
2010-07-26  1  2  3  4
2010-07-27  1  2  3  4
2010-07-28  1  2  3  4

df.update(df1)
print (df)
              a    b    c    d
2010-07-23  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-07-26  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
2010-07-27  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
2010-07-28  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
2010-07-29  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-07-30  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-08-02  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-08-03  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-08-04  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-08-05  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```